# Finitely presented morphism mean locally base change of finite type morphisms of noetherian schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am doing Vakil's note *Foundation of Algebraic Geomety* Exercise 9.3H:

> Let $\phi :X \to SpecB$ be a finitely presented morphism, prove that there exists a finite type morphism $ \psi:X' \to Spec\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_N]$ s.t. $\phi$ is a base change of $\psi$ by a morphism $\rho : SpecB \to Spec\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_N] $

The case when $X$ is affine is easy, say $X=SpecB[y_1,...,y_n]/<f_1,...,f_m>$, then let $\{c_j\}_{j=1}^N$ be the set of coefficients of $\{f_i\}$.  If we set $\rho$ to be induced by the map $x_j \mapsto c_j$, and $X'=Spec \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...x_N,y_1,...y_n]/<F_1,...F_m>$ where $F_i$ is $f_i$ with coefficient $c_j$ replaced by $x_j$, then $X$ is the base change of $X'$ by $\rho$.

If $X$ is not affine, then $X=\cup_{i=1}^k X_i$, with each $X_i$ is affine, I can define corresponding $X'_i$each $X_i$, and my problem is that I don't know how choose the generators of $\Gamma(X_i)$ to make sure those $X'_i$ can be glued together to form $X'$.

Any help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: The schemes $X_i$ are going to be glued along some subschemes $ X_{ij}$, you prob need to add the coefficients of these subschemes + the inclusion maps.

Comment: I just dunno how to handle  the subschems, let me assume $k=2$ and assume $X_1 \cap X_2= \cup Y_j$, with $X_1=SpecB[y_1,...,y_n]<f_1,...,f_m>$,$X_2=SpecB[z_1,...,z_r]/<g_1,...,g_s>$. I can also assume each $Y_i=(X_1)_{y_j}=(X_2)_{z_k}$.   Then I would have $Y_i$ equals the base change of $(X'_1)_{y_j}$ equals base change of $(X'_2)_{z_k}$, but I can't make sure $(X'_1)_{y_j}$ is isomorphic to $(X')_{z_k}$.